# Why would you assign an object to the window then return as module.exports?

Tags: javascript, module, export

I'm trying to parse this from a tutorial I'm going over.
My understanding is that module.exports returns the object to the calling importer.
What happens when you ALSO assign that to a global before returning the export?

```
// Instantiate a new game in the global scope at 800px by 600px

window.game = new Game(800, 600);

module.exports = game;
```

Comment: what happens? it's ALSO global - don't know why you'd do that though

Comment: OK that's what I thought.  Is it global when onLoad or does it wait for the package to be called to be global?

Comment: I'm confused about the use of `module.exports` in browser code - so it's a mystery in that regard too - if it's loaded in a script tag, `window.game` would be instantiated when the script loads

Comment: Cool. Thanks!  That confirmed my suspicions.  I'm not sure what's going on either.

Here's the tut. They may be transpiling to browser later?  Still getting started with it.

https://bengsfort.github.io/articles/making-a-js-game-part-1-game-engine/